# titanium: how do i change the text colors? white on black is wrong

Tags: titanium

i just downloaded the titanium gui, and opened my first project. I'm running windows 7. The  designers have opted for the classic "80s death metal basement" theme.

How do i change it so that it is white text on a black background? Because of this nerd-core style I'm assuming that most tokens won't work with a white background -so! Is there some "color scheme" i can change to - say "eclipse default" or "normal people"? which will mitigate me having to convert a whole bunch of different token-types to work on a white background?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open titanium studio.

go to `window->preferences->titanium studio->Themes`
I like to use `aptana studio 2.x`.
you can find other themes there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the elements when you create them, as far as I know.  Of course, you can create a utility function that does this for you

```
yourapp.ui.create = function(apiMethod, props) {
    props = props || {};
    props.color = '..';

    return apiMethod(props);
};
```

and then invoke it like

`label = yourapp.ui.create(Ti.UI.createLabel, {...});`

to populate the colors you want to be consistent.